# Display an image with SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I created a small FXML file with SceneBuilder, 3 buttons and 2 ImageView.

What i want to do is :

1. Run the app and display 2 images at start
2. When pressing `NEXT` button, display 2 other images.

My problem is not for swiching images, but to display one as an ImageView created by scene builder.

Here's my Controller class:

```
public class Controller {
    private Button Next; //1st button
    private Button J2inc; //2nd button
    private Button J1inc; /3rd button
    private ImageView Img1;
    private ImageView Img2;

    void Inc2(ActionEvent event) {
        //nothing for the moment
    }
    void Inc1(ActionEvent event) {
        //nothing for the moment
    }
    void Nextimg(ActionEvent event) {
        //nothing for the moment
    }
}
```

And my `start` method:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Css.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("P ");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I don't know how to initialize `ImageView img1` so it loads something.

Failed to add the FXML here so i'll only add the ImageView line:

```
  <ImageView fx:id="Img1" fitHeight="750.0" fitWidth="450.0" layoutY="22.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="450.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0" />
```

Comment: What does "Failed to add the FXML" mean? If you need to know how to format code, read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also note that it will help people read your Java code (and it will be highlighted correctly) if you use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: Yes that's what i meant, i'll read that again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize it in the controller, make the variable accessible by annotating it `@FXML`, and initialize it in the controller's `initialize()` method:

```
public class Controller {
    private Button Next; //1st button
    private Button J2inc; //2nd button
    private Button J1inc; /3rd button

    @FXML
    private ImageView Img1;

    private ImageView Img2;

    public void initialize() {
        Img1.setImage(new Image(...));
    }

    void Inc2(ActionEvent event) {
        //nothing for the moment
    }

    void Inc1(ActionEvent event) {
        //nothing for the moment
    }

    void Nextimg(ActionEvent event) {
        //nothing for the moment
    }
}
```

If you prefer to initialize it directly in the FXML, provide a value for the `image` attribute. In Scene Builder, you can select the `ImageView` and type the Image's URL in the "Image" field in the top right (under "Properties"). Be sure to read the [`Image` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) for how the string representation of the URL is interpreted.

Comment: @Bouji You should check the answer as correct if it is the solution to your problem.